# filter and manipulate object in array

Tags: javascript, filter

I'm trying to manipulate data in javascript after a query but without success...

The query got me an array of object:

```
{
    "keys": [
        "n"
    ],
    "length": 1,
    "_fields": [
        {
            "identity": {
                "low": 10,
                "high": 0
            },
            "labels": [
                "Lieu"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "UpdatedBy": "System",
                "Type": "Site / Bâtiment / Etage / Porte / Salle / Lit / Baie / Local",
                "CreatedBy": "System",
                "Updated": {...},
                "Environnement": "Modèle",
                "Code": "Bat12",
                "Nom": "ModèleLieu",
                "Created": {...}
            }
        }
    ],
    "_fieldLookup": {
        "n": 0
    }
}, 
{
      "keys": [
        "n"
    ],
    "length": 1,
    "_fields": [
        {
            "identity": {
                "low": 11,
                "high": 0
            },
            "labels": [
                "Lieudit"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "UpdatedBy": "production",
                "Type": "Lit / Baie / Local",
                "CreatedBy": "other",
                "Updated": {...},
                "Environnement": "production",
                "Code": "Bat13",
                "Nom": "lieudit",
                "Created": {...}
            }
        }
    ],
    "_fieldLookup": {
        "n": 0
    }
},
```

and i want to create an array of object with this format :

```
const element = {
    id: 10,
    Code: "Bat12",
    CreatedBy: "System",
    Environnement: "Modèle",
    Nom: "ModèleLieu",
    Type: "Site / Bâtiment / Etage / Porte / Salle / Lit / Baie / Local",
    UpdatedBy: "System",
},
{
    id: 11,
    Code: "Bat13",
    CreatedBy: "other",
    Environnement: "production",
    Nom: "lieudit",
    Type: "Lit / Baie / Local",
    UpdatedBy: "production",
};
```

which means bypass the object "CreatedBy", "UpdateBy" and keep the identity.low and the properties but at the same level than id.
namely that the properties may be different depending on the object, so I cannot use the name of the properties

So far  i've done this

```
            var componentArr = [];
            result.records.forEach((record) => {
                componentArr.push({
                    id: record._fields[0].identity.low,
                    name: record._fields[0].properties,
                });
            });
```

but "id" and the "properties" are not at the same level and "createdBy" and "update" are annoying me

Please help :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to get the desired result.

```js
const arr = [
  {
    keys: ["n"],
    length: 1,
    _fields: [
      {
        identity: {
          low: 10,
          high: 0,
        },
        labels: ["Lieu"],
        properties: {
          UpdatedBy: "System",
          Type: "Site / Bâtiment / Etage / Porte / Salle / Lit / Baie / Local",
          CreatedBy: "System",
          Updated: {},
          Environnement: "Modèle",
          Code: "Bat12",
          Nom: "ModèleLieu",
          Created: {},
        },
      },
    ],
    _fieldLookup: {
      n: 0,
    },
  },
  {
    keys: ["n"],
    length: 1,
    _fields: [
      {
        identity: {
          low: 11,
          high: 0,
        },
        labels: ["Lieudit"],
        properties: {
          UpdatedBy: "production",
          Type: "Lit / Baie / Local",
          CreatedBy: "other",
          Updated: {},
          Environnement: "production",
          Code: "Bat13",
          Nom: "lieudit",
          Created: {},
        },
      },
    ],
    _fieldLookup: {
      n: 0,
    },
  },
];

const result = arr.map((obj) => {
  const _fields = obj._fields[0];
  const id = _fields.identity.low;
  const {
    Code,
    CreatedBy,
    Environnement,
    Nom,
    Type,
    UpdatedBy,
  } = _fields.properties;
  return { id, Code, CreatedBy, Environnement, Nom, Type, UpdatedBy };
});

console.log(result);
```

**2**

```js
const arr = [
  {
    keys: ["n"],
    length: 1,
    _fields: [
      {
        identity: {
          low: 10,
          high: 0,
        },
        labels: ["Lieu"],
        properties: {
          UpdatedBy: "System",
          Type: "Site / Bâtiment / Etage / Porte / Salle / Lit / Baie / Local",
          CreatedBy: "System",
          Updated: {},
          Environnement: "Modèle",
          Code: "Bat12",
          Nom: "ModèleLieu",
          Created: {},
        },
      },
    ],
    _fieldLookup: {
      n: 0,
    },
  },
  {
    keys: ["n"],
    length: 1,
    _fields: [
      {
        identity: {
          low: 11,
          high: 0,
        },
        labels: ["Lieudit"],
        properties: {
          UpdatedBy: "production",
          Type: "Lit / Baie / Local",
          CreatedBy: "other",
          Updated: {},
          Environnement: "production",
          Code: "Bat13",
          Nom: "lieudit",
          Created: {},
        },
      },
    ],
    _fieldLookup: {
      n: 0,
    },
  },
];

const result = arr.map((obj) => {
  const _fields = obj._fields[0];
  const id = _fields.identity.low;
  const { Created, Updated, ...rest } = _fields.properties;
  return { id, ...rest };
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Should be simple. Try this:

```
    var data = [{
    "keys": ["n"],
    "length": 1,
    "_fields": [
        {
            "identity": {
                "low": 10,
                "high": 0
            },
            "labels": [
                "Lieu"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "UpdatedBy": "System",
                "Type": "Site / Bâtiment / Etage / Porte / Salle / Lit / Baie / Local",
                "CreatedBy": "System",
                "Updated":"",
                "Environnement": "Modèle",
                "Code": "Bat12",
                "Nom": "ModèleLieu",
                "Created":""
            }
        }
    ],
    "_fieldLookup": {"n": 0}

}, 
{
      "keys": [
        "n"
    ],
    "length": 1,
    "_fields": [
        {
            "identity": {
                "low": 11,
                "high": 0
            },
            "labels": [
                "Lieudit"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "UpdatedBy": "production",
                "Type": "Lit / Baie / Local",
                "CreatedBy": "other",
                "Updated": "",
                "Environnement": "production",
                "Code": "Bat13",
                "Nom": "lieudit",
                "Created": ""
            }
        }
    ],
    "_fieldLookup": {
        "n": 0
    }
}];


const newFormat = data.map(item => item._fields.map(field => {
    const {Updated, Created, ...props} = field.properties;
    return ({id: field.identity.low, ...props})

})).flat();


console.log(newFormat)
```